# Generics - Function return type the same as the parameter type?

Tags: java, generics

I want to make a function which returns a `List` of a data type the same as the data type of the parameter that was passed in. For example, I would call the function like this:

```
Object a = new Object();
List<Object> aList = foo(a);

Integer b = 5;
List<Integer> bList = foo(b);
```

Because I passed an `Object` to `foo`, it returned a `List<Object>` to me. When I pass an `Integer`, a `List<Integer>` is provided.

If this is not possible, I'm also okay with syntax like:

```
Object a = new Object();
List<Object> aList = foo(Object.class, a);
```

I've used generics plenty of times before but I don't know how to define a data type in the return type, and then say that the same data type will be used for the parameter.

```
List<T> foo(T data)
{
   ...
}
```

Or would it have to be like.... `List<T extends Object>`? I've never done generics this advanced before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the generic type right before the return type of the function say:

```
public static <T> List<T> foo(T data) {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I would do so using: 

[Function<T, R>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)? I can't do `Function<<T> <List<T>, T>`.

Comment: @Hatefiend in `Function<T,R>`, `T` is the type of the input argument and `R` is the type of the return argument, if it takes `T` and returns `T` then it will be `public static <T, T> Function<List<T>, T>foo(T data) { // ...}` this takes in a list of `T`s and returns something of type `T`

Comment: Thanks. That's strange that `Function<T, List<T>>` works but `List<T> foo(T bar)` doesn't . I don't understand that at all.

Comment: @Hatefiend Actually in my previous comment the `<T, T>` is not required since you are only using one generic type `T` thus `public static <T> Function<List<T>, T>foo(T data) { // ...}` will work just fine. What do you mean `List<T> foo(T bar)` doesn't work?

Comment: I may not be understanding you. I tried [this way](https://i.imgur.com/ZK4YvII.png) and [this way](https://i.imgur.com/XDvADs6.png) but I cannot define `T` in the same way that we did before when it was a regular function like `<T> List<T> foo(T bar)`. If possible I'd like to make this function we've made into a variable using `Function<T, R>`.

Comment: @Hatefiend Ok gotcha.You need to define `<T>` in the enclosing function, in this case `main`, if you want to use `T` inside such function, thus the correct syntax will be `public static <T> main(String[] args) { final Function<List<T>, T> foo; }`. You can also define it at `class` level if you are planning to use `T` across all your class.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot you could add a type before the return type.

```
<T> List<T> foo(T bar)
{
    ...
}
```