# Matching A parameter and return type using generics

Tags: java, generics

Can the return type be be matched to the parameter type using generics?

**Example case:**

I have an abstract class that will be implemented to import data from different POJO's, this class contains an abstrcact method importData.

The returned Object from importData must be of the same type as the Object passed to the method.

```
public abstract POJO importData(final POJO dataObject, final String messageId);
```

as the Object type is different for each implementation of the abstract method and the type does not extend another, how can the abstract method be defined so that the implementations return type and passed type MUST match?

### Edit:

**Tried and tested:**

```
public abstract <T> T importData(final T jaxbObject, final String messageId);
```

**Result:**

The return type of the method does not have to match the passed objects type.

Comment: Just wondering. If you used `public abstract <T> T importData(final T jaxbObject, final String messageId);`, how did the implementing class manage to return anything other than the original `jaxbObject`? The implementing class wouldn't know what object to instantiate and return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generics - Function return type the same as the parameter type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372157/generics-function-return-type-the-same-as-the-parameter-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a method level generic parameter:

```
public abstract <T> T importData(final T dataObject, final String messageId);
```

Beware though that this type `T` may vary for every call made. E.g following are possible:

```
POJO myPojo = myClass.importData(otherPojo, "messageId");
Integer someInt = myClass.importData(5, "otherMessageId");
String aSring = myClass.importData("Hello World", "anotherMessageId");
```

If that is not what you want, you may use the suggestion of a class level generic parameter by [@Leviand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398557/5515060).

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a letter for your class type, that will be assigned when your method is used, based on the type you use when the method is called

```
public abstract T importData(final T dataObject, final String messageId);
```

You can then, in your implementation, checking the type of your object for different behaviours

```
YourAbstractClass c = new YourAbstractClass() {
            @Override
            public <T> T importData(T dataObject, String messageId) {
                if(dataObject instanceof String){
                    //doSomething
                }else if (dataObject instanceof POJO){
                    //do POJO things
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
```

Comment: The only problem, with this solution is that the class has to bear the `T` parameter.

Comment: have tried this and tested in an implementation, but because T implicitly extends Object any object type can be returned

Comment: Ok, let me understand: so the T class that we are using must implement an interface? Tell me so I can edit the answer :)

Comment: the T class extends no interface and extends no additional object

Comment: So there's nothing more you can do, except checking what type you are receiving when your method is called, with _instanceof_ . I'll add en example in my answer

Comment: i get that this could be done with instanceof, however as it wont be me implementing the abstract class, the method has to be defined in a way that it could not be implemented incorrectly

Comment: the only way to achieve this is using an interface, and tell your method that the T class must implement that interface. No other way to do that :)